# Does an Stackoverflow occur in the JVM if the Activation Record is too small but there is still space left in the general stack?

Tags: jvm, stack, stack-overflow, activation-record

Every method is assigned its own activation record. Now, if there is a stack overflow on this activation record but there is still space left on the stack of the executing thread, does an overflow occur and the thread stops or will the activation record be assigned more space on the stack?
Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean with `activation record`?

Comment: I thought about activation records as the stack assigned to each called method

Comment: And what do you mean with a stack overflow happening but there still be memory available in the thread?

Comment: I imagine the activation record being located on the stack of the thread. So it is like a stack on a stack. I wonder what happens if the activation record is overflowing

Comment: There is no stack on the stack. Only the topmost (last called method) can add something to the stack and only the last element on the stack can be removed. A `StackOverflowError` only occurs when there is no place to call a method (or similar) left on the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call “activation record” is normally know as [activation *frame*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.5) or [(stack) frame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se21/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6).

A frame is always large enough to hold all local variables and temporary operand values of the method execution it belongs to. Hence, there is no possibility for a stack overflow to occur *within* a frame. When a method about to be invoked, a new frame for the invoked method will be placed on the stack but if there is not enough room on the stack for the frame, a `StackOverflowError` will be thrown.

There might be special operations pushing more data to the stack. For example, synchronization may require more data to be stored on the stack under certain circumstances. In such situations, a `StackOverflowError` may occur in the middle of a method execution if there’s not enough space on the stack.

But it’s debatable whether that could be seen as a frame expansion, rather than pushing additional non-frame data to the stack. A frame is normally seen as a fixed size entity, as the whole point of it, is to have a fixed size data structure, to eliminate the need for frequently altering the stack pointer.